# Createing a new Index in SQL when current records don't meet that index

Tags: mysql, indexing

I'd like to add an index to a table that already contains data.  I know that there a few records currently in the table that are not unique with this new index.  Clearly, MySQL won't let me add the index until all of them are.

I need a query to identify the rows which currently have the same index.  I can then delete or modify these rows as necessary.  The new index contains 6 fields.

Thanks-

Jonathan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `GROUP BY` with [HAVING](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/select.html) to find the offending fields.

```
SELECT   IndexField
FROM     YourTable
GROUP BY IndexField
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```